# Invalid Avro object container in a stream. The header cannot be recognized. - How do I parse message in the blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, iot, avro

I have devices which send messages to IOT Hub. I am using [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing) feature of IoT Hub to route the messages to blob storage.

I see that all the messages are reaching the `Blob` storage. But it's storing in appended format. all the message appended one after other.

I understand that we can configure `chunk size` and `frequency` but my requirement is to store one message each in one blob. Is it possible?

Or

How do I parse each message based on timestamp?

Here is the avro message

```
 Objavro.codecnullavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"Message","namespace":"Microsoft.Azure.Devices","fields":
```

Here is the Azure Function Code

```
 using (var reader = AvroContainer.CreateGenericReader(myBlob))
        {
            while (reader.MoveNext())
            {
                foreach (dynamic record in reader.Current.Objects)
                {
                    var bodyText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Body);
                    log.LogInformation($"AvroRecord = {bodyText}");
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get error like this

> Invalid Avro object container in a stream. The header cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

> But it's storing in appended format. all the message appended one
>   after other.

What type of blob did you create it as:  block, append, or page blob?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs